# Prevent F11 keydown on iframes on page?

Tags: javascript, iframe, event-handling, keydown

I have several iframes in a popup window with each a target of a form that posts to different sites.

I currently have the following to prevent <kbd>F11</kbd> keydown on the document:

```
document.onkeydown = function () {
    if (event.keyCode == 122) {
         event.keyCode = 0;
         return false;
    }
 }
```

**Goal:** Prevent the user from viewing the URL before and after the iframe loads.

**Question:** Is there a better alternative to meeting the goal instead of handling a keydown event? Is it possible to handle such an event for an iframe that holds the contents of another domain? Is it possible to still listen for and prevent onkey events on an iframe eventhough iframes are incapable of having any onkey attributes?

The solution should be vanilla js or use as little jQuery references as possible.

Comment: Your "goal" sounds like you expect this to provide some kind of security. Preventing a particular keypress which happens (in some browsers) to do something you don't want the user to do (fullscreen? were you thinking of F12 for debugging tools?) does not stop a user doing what they like with the content that has been sent to their browser.

Comment: Hahaha this must be a joke! You think users won't be able to read the URL they open?

Comment: I know, I'm working on a project and this is a "requirement". It is a bit much and I know that it is pointless, but I am not too familiar with js to declare that this cannot be done. I'm only working with IE. Main window opens a popup and redirects. So the URL for the page is hidden. Currently blocking on the document but the iframes still allow. If it is not possible, I just need a good reason and some support.